# How to implement export to excel functionality for the ag grid having sparkline chart (from highcharts library) integrated?

Tags: charts, highcharts, angular7, export-to-excel, ag-grid-angular

I am having sparkline charts integrated with ag grid and it's working as expected but as per requirement, I also have to implement *export to excel functionality which should export all the row details from ag-grid along with the sparkline chart details.*

**Things tried:**

I have tried most common way to export the details from ag-grid and which is working as expected. Things that I can see while exporting the excel sheet is only the data points values (numbers) that I have passed to plot sparkline chart per row instead of exporting the **HTML of the chart**.

With the export of data values only, I don't think it gives much detailed information to the user.

**Expected Outcome:**

I want to export the ag grid details along with the sparkline charts **HTML contents**. That simply means, if the contents are exported from Ag-grid having sparkline chart, the actual sparkline chart should be exported instead of data points used to plot charts.

**In common terms, I want to picturise the sparkline chart as it is in the exported sheet instead of showing values in form of numbers**

Is there any way to export entire chart which is already plotted on web app, and I want same to be presented into excel sheet for better representation of sparkline charts when export to excel should happen (*highcharts library*)?

**Note:**
I have used **ag-grid** and integrated sparkline charts from **highcharts library**. The entire functionality is implemented with help of **Angular 7**

Comment: You would like to have an image of the chart inside the excel. Am I correct?

Comment: Yes, having image of sparkline chart in excel from ag grid export that might be helpful. Can you please help me with a way to do the same?

Comment: The issue seems to be complex and I've never seen a working example. Higcharts doesn't provide that solution. There might be a chance to generate the image and then include it in excel, but you will have to work with different files, technologies, languages which doesn't sound like a simple task. If I were you, I would start with exporting the chart to png/img then I would try to find some solution how to add it to a spreadsheet.

Comment: @AmeyDesai Did you find any solution ? I am also looking for same.

Comment: I wanted to implement the same feature. I have connected to zendesk support for ag-grid. For support they need enterprise ag-grid licence key then they give you the access. After a long mail thread, we came to know that AG-Grid is not giving such functionality. They will be implementing this in near future. If u have access to zendesk support you can track the request -   AG-6323 [Sparkline] Allow exporting sparkline visualization to Excel